# Changing key output

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making a program that will take keystrokes entered and change the output to form a message of my choosing. I'm thinking of using GetAsyncKeystate() to see if a key is down, but I'm not sure how to change the value of the key pressed.

Comment: You need to provide specific information. Is this a console application or a GUI application? Where does *output* have to go? Command prompt? Some control? A file? Somewhere else? What is the translation *"of your choosing"*?

Comment: My Apologies, essentially Im making a small program to screw with my friends. For 20 seconds (Program ceases to execute after 20 seconds) it will take anything they type (say into their address bar or any other program) and change it to a letter in an array. The goal is to make anything they type turn into something else, say "hello".

Comment: @Ripsaw, you could write a device driver, but would it really be worth it?

Comment: Fairly involved project, for 20 seconds of fun. I suppose you could infiltrate all running processes (using a global hook, for example), and load your own keyboard layout. It'll be somewhat of a challenge cleaning up the mess when the 20 seconds are over, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is a [low-level keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You don't get a ton of context, but you do get the raw keystrokes.  If you need context, then you're probably looking at a [text service via TSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that tends to get complex quickly.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it doesn't look like you can modify keyboard input in a low-level keyboard hook. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#wh_keyboard_llhook): *"The WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook enables you to **monitor** keyboard input events about to be posted in a thread input queue."*